# Mongodb driver deadlock in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, deadlock, mongodb-.net-driver

I have simple asp.net WebApi project with two controllers. 
First controller use **System.Linq** and has a deadlock under heavy loading. Second use **MongoDB.Driver.Linq** and work great.

I used ab -c 10 -n 200000 -p post -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -T 'application/json' 'http://localhost:1989/api/SystemLinq/find'

**Why using System.linq I have a deadlock?**

Deadlock occurs only in case when after reading data throw new Exception. Exception I catch with IExceptionFilter. Full project https://github.com/artyukh/AspNetMongoDeadlock

Controller with deadlock

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Linq;
using TestDeadlock.Core;

namespace TestDeadlock.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SystemLinqController : Controller
    {
        private MongoContext _context;

        public SystemLinqController(MongoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("find")]
        public void Find([FromBody]AuthenticateInputDTO input)
        {
            var result = _context.UserSet.AsQueryable().Where(u => u.Email == input.Username).FirstOrDefault();
            if (result == null)
                throw new BusinessException("User not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Working controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using TestDeadlock.Core;

namespace TestDeadlock.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class MongoLinqController : Controller
    {
        private MongoContext _context;

        public MongoLinqController(MongoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("find")]
        public void Find([FromBody]AuthenticateInputDTO input)
        {
            var result = _context.UserSet.AsQueryable().Where(u => u.Email == input.Username).FirstOrDefault();
            if (result == null)
                throw new BusinessException("User not found");
        }
    }
}
```

ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");

            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionFilter());
            });

            services.AddMvc();

            services.Configure<MongoSettings>(options =>
            {
                options.ConnectionString
                    = Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection:ConnectionString").Value;
                options.Database
                    = Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection:Database").Value;
            });
            services.AddSingleton<MongoContext>();
        }
```

GlobalExceptionFilter

```
public class GlobalExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            Exception exception = context.Exception;
            string errorMessage;
            int statusCode = 500;
            if (exception is BusinessException)
            {
                statusCode = 400;
                errorMessage = exception.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage = "Internal Error";
            }

            var response = new ErrorResponse
            {
                Message = errorMessage
            };

            context.Result = new ObjectResult(response)
            {
                StatusCode = statusCode,
                DeclaredType = typeof(ErrorResponse),
                ContentTypes = new MediaTypeCollection { "application/json" }
            };
        }
    }
```